# Comparison of Scala (latest 2.10) versus Groovy++ (latest 0.9.1?)

Tags: scala, jvm, static-typing, groovy++

I've just watched a [video of the Groovy inventor](http://macstrac.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/scala-is-awesome.html?m=1), James Strachan, in which he goes on quite passionately about loving Scala. That caused me to want to find out more about Groovy which lead me to Groovy++. [Groovy++](http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/wiki/Welcome) is a statically typed and compiled version of Groovy (which is apparently completely dynamic).

I attempted to figure out what Groovy++ (latest version at 0.9.1?) was in contrast with Scala (latest version at 2.10). The activity on the [Groovy++ forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/groovyplusplus) doesn't have very much recent activity regarding the latest version for which to be able to draw much information.

So, is there a nice simple comparison/contrast of Scala to Groovy++? I am not interested in Groovy itself (other than being the basis upon which Groovy++ is designed) as I want to compare statically compiled features side by side. A simple advanages/disadvantages (i.e. tradeoffs) list is basically what I am seeking without having to do dozens to hundreds of hours of research and experimentation.

Thank you, in advance, for anything you can contribute to this contrast and compare query.

Comment: I count the seconds until this gets closed because of bla bla bla otherwise I would be interested in some serious answers

Comment: Me, too. SO is worse than WP these days.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Groovy++ project died last year-ish, apparently due to schism between SpringSource Groovy team and non-SpringSource supported Groovy++ team (led by Alex T. who now seems to be an active contributor to the Kotlin project along with, ironically enough James Strachan).

Was pretty ugly, Alex T. was understandably pissed off about getting the rug swept out from under him (Spring Groovy announced their own static Groovy). Check through some of the Old Nabble entries for the back & forth, heated at times. Not sure how things stand now, competition brings out the best & worst, maybe both sides are over it...

At any rate I too bailed, ditching Groovy for Scala and am overwhelmingly happy to have made that decision -- Scala rocks, I dare say, it Scocks™, give Scala a try! ;-)

Groovy was a great transition-to-JVM language for me, but the lack of compile time guarantees just drove me nuts after awhile (probably why static Groovy project(s) came into being in the first place)

Comment: Thx for the story, so that's why nobody heard of g++, well I would suggest scala too and if you _haveto_ use dynamic give Clojure a try it's not bad